# Ionic 3:- On continous navigation from rootpage to another page on Navcontroller. Page becomes irresponsive.

Tags: angular, ionic3

When i push a page(tabbed page) from my rootpage(Dashboard) on navcontroller and return back by setrootpage. When i perform similar thing few times my rootpage become irresponsive for sometime without showing any error in console. The only thing i can notice is continous change of z-index which i see in developer console in elements tab.

Details of my environment is following:-

> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
> Node              : v7.4.0
> npm               : 4.0.5
> OS                : OS X El Capitan
> Xcode             : Xcode 6.3.1 Build version 6D1002
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : /Users/chetan.chauhan/Documents/android/android-sdk-macosx/
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Comment: please create a plunker or something to reproduce the issue

Comment: sure I’ll give it a shot. But i am not sure i'll be able to create identical environment with ionic 3's default dynamic styles.